# Issue with Density Plot using GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a density plot for 2 groups and below is my code.
library(ggplot2)

```
#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfiles2Best$V2, myfilesL2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("T", "L")))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Score)) +
        geom_density(aes(color = Group)) + xlim(0,16)
```

Below is the image of the output.
[image]

and when I change the data frame by changing the location of the column as shown below this is how my plot looks like.

```
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfilesL2Best$V2, myfiles2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("L", "T")))
```

[image]

Individually, this is how they look like.

```
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfiles2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("T"))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Score)) +
        geom_density(aes(color = Group)) + xlim(0,16)
```

[image]

```
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfilesL2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("L"))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Score)) +
        geom_density(aes(color = Group)) + xlim(0,16)
```

[image]

This is totally wrong, anything wrong with my setup

```
rownumber  score group
1   8   T
2   8   L
3   7   T
4   7   L
5   9   T
6   8   L
7   8   T
8   7   L
9   8   T
10  8   L
11  8   T
12  9   L
13  8   T
14  8   L
15  8   T
16  8   L
17  9   T
18  7   L
19  9   T
20  7   L
21  8   T
22  10  L
23  8   T
24  8   L
25  9   T
26  8   L
27  8   T
28  8   L
29  9   T
30  8   L
31  7   T
32  10  L
33  8   T
34  10  L
35  8   T
36  7   L
37  8   T
38  7   L
39  11  T
40  9   L
41  8   T
42  9   L
43  8   T
44  10  L
45  8   T
46  9   L
47  8   T
48  8   L
49  8   T
50  7   L
51  9   T
52  8   L
53  8   T
54  9   L
55  8   T
56  7   L
57  7   T
58  9   L
59  10  T
60  8   L
```

Comment: Difficult to say without a reproducible example + without code for generating the individual plots

Comment: @erocoar Updated

Comment: I'm guessing that `rep(c("L", "T"))` is not doing what you think it is doing. Also, instead of just saying that it is wrong, try to explain how it is wrong. We can't reproduce anything without data.

Comment: I'm guessing you're expecting the individual plots to have the same shape as the combined plots. I suspect the combined plot is using different bins, since the combined data will have a different range than the individual data. Try specifying binwidth, that might make them match. Hard to know without data.

Comment: @JonSpring Data Provided

Comment: As @Axeman noted, your first two charts have similar shapes because you are feeding them the same data. The odd rows of your `myfiles2Best$V2` data are assigned to group `T` and the even rows are assigned to group `L`, because R recycles the two values in your `Group` vector. When you swap the order, it seems that you have identical data between the two charts (makes sense if your vectors have even length), but in one case L is in the first row and in the other T is in the first row. That difference determines which color ggplot maps to which value, explaining why the colors swap.

Comment: There is still no clarification on what is "totally wrong". So this question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2::geom_density` uses the base R `density` function to compute density. (see `?geom_density`.) This requires a parameter for smoothing, which by default uses a rule named "nrd0", which was picked for "historical and compatibility reasons." (see `?density`.) You will get density plots with different appearances depending on this parameter.

From `?bandwidth`:

> bw.nrd0 implements a rule-of-thumb for choosing the bandwidth of a Gaussian kernel density estimator. It defaults to 0.9 times the minimum of the standard deviation and the interquartile range divided by 1.34 times the sample size to the negative one-fifth power (= Silverman's ‘rule of thumb’, Silverman (1986, page 48, eqn (3.31))) unless the quartiles coincide when a positive result will be guaranteed.

In your example, the two subgroups look like they have different standard deviations and IQRs, so it makes sense to me that they would look different depending on whether that smoothing parameter is calculated for them collectively (as in the case with the combined plot) or individually.

If you want your density plots to correspond between a grouped and individual basis, specify the bandwidth manually:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = score)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = group), bw = 0.3) + 
  xlim(0,16)

ggplot(subset(df, group == "L"), aes(x = score)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = group), bw = 0.3) + 
  xlim(0,16)

ggplot(subset(df, group == "T"), aes(x = score)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = group), bw = 0.3) + 
  xlim(0,16)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is happening is when you swap the groups from


`#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfiles2Best$V2, myfilesL2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("T", "L")))`
to

`#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(Score = c(myfilesL2Best$V2, myfiles2Best$V2)
                  , Group = rep(c("L", "T")))`
It maintains the same graph but only changes the groups label.

Comment: It might be worth examining your data closely here. It sounds like you're appending the two `V2` vectors one after the other, and then assigning alternating L / T / L / T / L / T groups to each row in turn, so that L and T do not correspond to your two sources, rather about your first group is in L and half in T. I bet that's not what you intended.